# Configure Linux font path?

Tags: linux, fonts

Is there a way to configure the font path in Linux easily using a PATH-like variable or a configuration file?

I keep most of my fonts in Dropbox, so I'd like to set the font path to be something like:

```
/usr/share/fonts:$HOME/.fonts:$HOME/Dropbox/Documents/Fonts
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just symlink a subfolder of .fonts to a folder in your Dropbox.

E.g., from the commandline:

`ln -s $HOME/Dropbox/Documents/Fonts ~/.fonts/Dropbox-Fonts`

Comment: Sweet! I didn't know it would climb down into subdirectories.